# Laravel SELECT SUM 2 columns Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
SELECT 
     SUM(username = 'benjamin') as c1, 
     SUM(email = 'benjamin@hotmail.com') as c2 
FROM users WHERE active = 0
```

I have a mysql query need to check 2 columns match

But now I need to write it into Laravel Eloquent

anyone know how to do this in Eloquent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
User::where('active', 0)
    ->select(DB::raw("SUM(username = 'benjamin') as c1, SUM(email = 'benjamin@hotmail.com') as c2"))
    ->get();
```

Hope this helps!